# deploy из github имея только sftp

Tags: git, sftp

Есть удаленный сервер доступ к нему только через sftp. Необходимо настроить deploy из git репозитория.

Comment: примонтируйте нужный каталог и делайте всё, что требуется, локально.

Answer (score 1):

Написать скрипт, который:

1. делает pull в локальную копию
2. заливает эту копию (без подкаталога .git) по ftp